# Shouldn't Oozie/Sqoop jar location be configured during package installation?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm using HDP 2.4 in CentOS 6.7.

I have created the cluster with Ambari, so Oozie was installed and configured by Ambari.

I got two errors while running Oozie/Sqoop related to jar file location. The first concerned `postgresql-jdbc.jar`, since the Sqoop job is incrementally importing from Postgres. I added the `postgresql-jdbc.jar` file to HDFS and pointed to it in `workflow.xml`:

```
<file>/user/hdfs/sqoop/postgresql-jdbc.jar</file>
```

It solved the problem. But the second error seems to concern `kite-data-mapreduce.jar`. However, doing the same for this file:

```
<file>/user/hdfs/sqoop/kite-data-mapreduce.jar</file>
```

does not seem to solve the problem:

> Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class
>   [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], main() threw exception,
>   org/kitesdk/data/DatasetNotFoundException
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/kitesdk/data/DatasetNotFoundException

It seems strange that this is not automatically configured by Ambari and that we have to copy jar files into HDFS as we start getting errors.

Is this the correct methodology or did I miss some configuration step?

Comment: I think you should add these jars into the `lib` directory of the basepath of you workflow. The basepath is directory where your workflow.xml is stored. You need to created this directory and store all the custom jars your workflow needs. It will load them in the classpath.

Comment: @YoungHobbit, I used the `lib` directory as you described. The result is the same. I see the JAR files being loaded, as before, but I still get the `org/kitesdk/data/DatasetNotFoundException`. This exception does not happen if the origin table has no new columns. In that case, the oozie job runs as scheduled and sqoop just says it does not have new rows to import. But when I add a new row to the table, this exception occurs. It is strange, because I can run the sqoop job directly (instead of through oozie) and it runs OK.

Comment: OK, I just noticed that in fact there are changes after adding the JAR. The exception was `org/kitesdk/data/mapreduce/DatasetKeyOutputFormat` and after adding the JAR file it becomes `org/kitesdk/data/DatasetNotFoundException` so it seems I'm on the right track. Some other JAR file is needed perhaps.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the property `oozie.use.system.libpath=true` in the `job.properties` file. Then only custom jar you need to add to the lib directory, all the sqoop related jars will be added from the /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_*/sqoop/*.jar

Comment: @YoungHobbit, thanks. I am using `oozie.use.system.libpath=true`. I copied all Sqoop JAR's into HDFS, e.g. `hadoop fs -put /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/sqoop/lib/*.jar oozie/lib`, to make it work. Some of them probably were already on `hdfs:///user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20160317123503/sqoop`. Would you care to provide an answer?

Comment: If you are using the above `libpath` property then you should not copy the jars. Also do not copy any of your jars into the oozie share libs. Copy your workflow specific jars into the lib directory of the workflow application path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108410/discussion-between-joao-m-s-silva-and-younghobbit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to the missing jars in the classpath. I would suggest you to use the property `oozie.use.system.libpath=true` in the `job.properties` file. All the sqoop related jars will be added automatically in the classpath. Then add only custom jar you need to the lib directory of the workflow application path., all the sqoop related jars will be added from the `/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<timestamp>/sqoop/*.jar`.